# why can't I create a calendar?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, google-signin

I used [Google SignIn](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/ServerAuthCodeActivity.java) in my SignActivity as below:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .requestProfile()
            .build();
// [END configure_signin]

// [START build_client]
// Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
// options specified by gso.
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
// [END build_client]

SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);
signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
```

Now I am able to get token, email name and other informations.

And I followed [this example](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert#auth) to create a calendar for given email in my other activity as below :

```
//for calendar start
static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1000;
static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 1001;
static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 1002;
private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";
private static final String[] SCOPES = { CalendarScopes.CALENDAR };
GoogleAccountCredential mCredential;
com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar calendar;
//for calendar end

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    createBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // I take the email from my sign activity.
            String emailName = SignActivity.getPref(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, getApplicationContext());
            mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                    getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
                    .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff())
                    .setSelectedAccountName(emailName);
            if (isDeviceOnline()) {
                new MakeRequestTask(mCredential).execute();
            } else {
                descriptionEditText.setText("No network connection available.");
            }
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

and my MakeRequestTask constructor :

```
HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
mService = new Calendar.Builder(
         transport, jsonFactory, credential)
         .setApplicationName("Test")
         .build();
```

and and my problem is in doInBackground function at first line in the try block it can not execute and do other codes but oddly I don't get any error :

```
try{
    com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar createdCalendar = mService.calendars().insert(calendar).execute();

    CalendarListEntry calendarListEntry = new CalendarListEntry();
    calendarListEntry.setId(createdCalendar.getId());
    calendarListEntry.setBackgroundColor(backGroundColor);
    calendarListEntry.setForegroundColor(foreGroundColor);
    // Insert the new calendar list entry
    CalendarListEntry createdCalendarListEntry = mService.calendarList().insert(calendarListEntry).execute();
        Log.i("summary", createdCalendarListEntry.getSummary());
    }catch (IOException e){
            Log.i("test1", e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: have you tried this quickstart by Google? https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android

Comment: yes it worked but this made me sign in again but I already signed in. I created Web application OAuth 2.0 client IDs for GoogleSignInOptions to get id token. Is this a problem?

Comment: There were some changes to the signin on Google play services 8.3 - http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/11/whats-new-in-google-play-services-83.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my createBtn onClick function

I added below codes to the top of other codes:

> I'm not sure this is the real solution. But in my old codes there were no ask for permission for calendar but now it is asking me to give a permission.

```
if (mCredential.getSelectedAccountName() == null) {
    chooseAccount();
}
```

now it is working.